# How to Calculate Crime Density?

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, r-sp, r-sf

Overall Goal: Calculate densities of crime in a grid structure of a US city. Each grid square should be 100 meters square. I have a data frame ***crime.inc*** listing individual crime instance lat and lon; something like this:

```
incident id   lat       lon
1001         45.123   -122.456
1002         45.456   -122.789
```

Next, I have a predefined grid ***g*** which is a regular grid

```
predef.grid <- data.frame(lat = seq(from = 44, to = 45, by = 0.1),lon = seq(from = -122, to = -121, by = 0.1))
id <- rownames(predef.grid)  # add row ids
predef.grid <- cbind(id=id, predef.grid)  # add row ids
```

My output needs to be something like this, each row is a unique grid in the predefined grid, with count being the number of incidents within that grid:

```
id      lat   lon       count
1001  45.123  -122.789    4
1002  45.456  -122.987    5
```

I've tried using sp, sf, raster, rgeos in various forms, never quite getting the rock over the hill! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain how your `predef.grid` object represents a grid of 100m square?

Comment: @sebdalgarno the grid is loosely based around the logic that 0.001 as it relates to a lat/lon coordinate is approx = 100m. So a change from 45.123 to 45.124 is around 100m. This isn't exact, and my example above doesn't reflect this logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that "0.001 as it relates to a lat/lon coordinate is approx = 100m" may not hold up. The distance will depend on where in the world you are, but using example data from your region:

```
library(sf)

# adjust latitude by 0.001
df <- data.frame(lat = c(45.123, 45.124),  lon = c(-122.789, -122.789))
df.sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
> st_distance(df.sf)
Units: m
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]   0.0000 111.1342
[2,] 111.1342   0.0000

#Or, if we adjust the longitude by 0.001:
df <- data.frame(lat = c(45.123, 45.123),  lon = c(-122.789, -122.790))
df.sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
> st_distance(df.sf)
Units: m
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  0.00000 78.67796
[2,] 78.67796  0.00000
```

Here is an alternative solution to your problem using `sf` package:

```
# add a few more points to make it more interesting
df <- data.frame(id = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005),
                 lat = c(45.123, 45.123, 45.126, 45.121, 45.130), 
                 lon = c(-122.456, -122.457, -122.444, -122.442, -122.445))

# convert to an sf object and set projection (crs) to 4326 (lon/lat)
df.sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# transform to UTM (Zone 10) for distance
df.utm <- st_transform(df.sf, "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

# create a 100m grid on these points
grid.100 <- st_make_grid(x = df.utm, cellsize = c(100, 100))

# plot to make sure
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df.utm, size = 3) +
  geom_sf(data = grid.100, alpha = 0)
```

[image]
    # convert grid to sf (not sfc) and add an id column
    grid.sf <- st_sf(grid.100)
    grid.sf$id <- 1:nrow(grid.sf)

```
# find how many points intersect each grid cell by using lengths() to get the number of points that intersect each grid square
grid.sf$count <- st_intersects(grid.sf, df.utm) %>% lengths()
```

Plot to check

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = grid.sf, alpha = 0.5, aes(fill = as.factor(count))) +
  geom_sf(data = df.utm, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_discrete("Number of Points")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the assumption that 0.001 = 100m is not exact. It's meant to be more of a general parameter for grid spacing (for my purposes). Thank you very much for the insight into sf()!

Comment: glad it helped @beavertrapper07. Please don't forget to mark as 'Answered' if it did indeed answer your question.

Comment: how do I convert the UTM distance figures in sf.grid back to actual lat, lon coordinates? Trying to find centroid of each grid in actual lat/lon @sebdalgarno

Comment: you can transform back to lat/lon with `st_transform(sf.grid, 4326)`, where 4326 is the epsg for WGS 84

Answer (score 0):

For what the data on the question suggest, the lat and lon have only three decimal. Therefore, you could simply use dplyr to group by location, not needing to use GIS packages.

```
library(dplyr)
densities <- crime.inc %>% group_by(lat,lon) %>% 
             summarise(count=n())
```

This way you would lose the ID. if you want to keep the ID

```
library(dplyr)
densities <- crime.inc %>% group_by(lat,lon) %>% 
             rename(count=n())
```

Comment: Andre Costa YES! This replaces 500+ lines of my code that doesn't work! Thank you much

Comment: No, this is not a 100m grid. You can't even have a regular 100m x 100m grid in regular lat-long coordinates.